# Selected Category value in Dropdown from Category Tree

Tags: php

This is my Code for creating n-level category.

```
function fetchCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {

    if (!is_array($user_tree_array))
        $user_tree_array = array();

    $sql = "SELECT `cat_id`, `cat_name`, `parent_id` FROM `category` WHERE  `parent_id` = $parent  ORDER BY cat_id ASC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            $user_tree_array[] = array("id" => $row->cat_id, "name" => $spacing . $row->cat_name);
            $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row->cat_id, $spacing . '&nbsp;-', $user_tree_array );
        }
    }
    return $user_tree_array;
}

$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
```

Displaying all categories in drop-down

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
<td> Category:</td><td><select name="parentcat" id="parentcat" onchange="getText(this)">

    <option selected value="Root">--Root Level--</option>
        <?php
     foreach($categoryList as $cl) {
         ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $cl["id"] ?>"><?php echo $cl["name"]; ?></option>
     <?php }  ?>
```

Now I wanted to display selected parent name in dropdown. If a category name is `Laptop` it's parent name would be `'Electronics`. I wanted Electronics to be showed up in dropdown.

My database would be like this:

```
cat_id | cat_name   | parent_id
-------------------------------
 1     | Electronics| 0
-------------------------------
 2     | Laptops    | 1
```

I want this `Electronics` in dropdown If I select `Laptops`.

Comment: how we decide that laptop parent is electronics?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know where is selected?
Example for a $_GET['id']

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
     if ($val['id'] === $id) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   return null;
}

$selected_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
?>
<option <?=(searchForId($selected_id,$categoryList))?'selected':''?> value="Root">--Root Level--</option>
<?php
foreach($categoryList as $cl) {
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $cl["id"] ?>"><?php echo $cl["name"]; ?></option>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Yes I am getting value by this: $id=$_GET['id];

Comment: Okay, then try my example :)

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working, it is giving me all result in dropdown

Comment: i have change the code for the search in multidimensional array!